# PHP foreach array strange behavior

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have code with two foreach, first with **&**, second without:

```
$a = array(1, 2);

foreach ( $a as &$v ) {
    $v *= 1;
}

print_r($a); // output: array(1, 2)

$b = array();

foreach ( $a as $v ) {
    $b[] = $v;
}

print_r($b); // output: array(1, 1)
```

Why in second foreach $v always = 1 and array b is (1, 1) instead (1, 2)?

Comment: Try `print_r($a)`? What does it show?

Comment: Because `$v` is a reference to guess what?

Comment: `$v` is the address location.

Comment: Read warning here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @u_mulder  Thanks

Comment: $v is a reference. I'm guessing it prints array(1, 2) the first time because the collector hasn't got its hands on the value variable, but the second time you iterate it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of $a[1] in the first loop of the second foreach, if you do a var_dump instead, you get output that indicates it is a reference:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(2)
}
```

So, on the second foreach `$a[1]` (which is actually `&$v;` becomes `1`), which then is the second value that comes out of `$a` in the loop, because it is actually:

```
$a[
   1,
   &$v
];
```

If you were to reassign $v after the loop, you would get the new value in the array instead:

```
<?php

$a = [1, 2];
foreach ( $a as &$v ) {
    $v = $v;
}
var_dump($a); // output: array(int(1), &int(2))
$b = [];
foreach ( $a as $v ) {
    $b[] = $v;
}
$v = 3;
var_dump($a); // output: array(int(1), &int(3))
```